# Weibel Lemma 1.6.2. definition of exact category.

Tags: definition, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The following is Lemma 1.6.2. from Weibel's *Homological Algebra*.$\newcommand{\C}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}$

> Let $\C{C} \subset \C{A}$ be a full subcategory of an abelian category $\C{A}$.
>
> 1. $\C{C}$ is additive $\Leftrightarrow$ $0 \in \C{C}$, and $\C{C}$ is closed under $\oplus$.
> 2. $\C{C}$ is abelian and $\C{C} \subset \C{A}$ is exact $\Leftrightarrow$ $\C{C}$ is additive, and $\C{C}$ is closed under $\ker$ and $\coker$.

---

My doubt is in Point 2. What does Weibel mean by "$\C{C}$ is exact"? Up until this point, there was never any definition of a *category* being exact. (Going through the index at the end seems to suggest that there is never any such definition.)

However, earlier in the book, there was the following definition:

> A subcategory $\C{B}$ of an abelian category $\C{A}$ is called an *abelian subcategory* if it is abelian, and an exact sequence in $\C{B}$ is also exact in $\C{A}$.

Is that what is meant above in Point 2? That is,

> $\C{C}$ is an abelian subcategory of $\C{A}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\C{C}$ is additive, and $\C{C}$ is closed under $\ker$ and $\coker$.

(I am hoping that even someone who hasn't read Weibel can answer it by seeing what should be the correct statement that is equivalent to being additive and closed under $\ker$ and $\coker$.)

Comment: He's not calling the category exact.  He is calling the natural inclusion $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ exact as a functor.

Comment: @Randall: Ohh, I see. This is still slightly weird since "exact functor" is defined two pages later, but that makes sense. So I believe that what I concluded finally is correct after all. Could you confirm that?